# Least absolute deviation for item prices

Tags: matrices, statistics, approximation

How would I calculate the values of $A,B,C$ using **least absolute deviation**?

$R = 1$

$2A + B$ = $C + R$.

$B + C$ = $5A$.

$A + C + 2R$ = $B + 4R$.

$A + B + C$ = $6.33R$.

Using least squares approximation, I was able to get the approximate solutions:

$A = 1.0440R$

$B = 2.1155R$

$C = 3.1375R$

Is it possible to use least absolute deviation? If so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a method to calculate the least absolute deviation solution that goes back at least to Gauss (see [Least Absolute Deviations](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-1-4684-8574-5)). Please note that the least absolute deviation solution is rarely unique (one of the differences to linear least squares).

Your over-determined linear equation system is given by $Ax=b$ with:

$$A =
 \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
  2 & 1 & -1 \\
  -5 & 1 & 1 \\
  1 & -1 & 1 \\
  1 & 1 & 1 \end{array} \right) ~~~~~\textrm{and}~~~~~~
b =
 \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
  1  \\
  0 \\
  2 \\
  6.33
 \end{array} \right)$$

**There is a a** least absolute deviation solution that is given by $A_Sx=b_S$ where $A_S$ and $b_S$ are given by picking $3$ rows of the system. There are $\binom{4}{3}=4$ such possibilities. Pick some solution of these four possibilities where $\|Ax-b\|_1$ is minimal.

Here they are

$x_{123} = A_{123}^{-1}b_{123} = (1.0000,2.0000,3.0000)^T$

$x_{124} = A_{124}^{-1}b_{124} \approx (1.0550,2.0825,3.1925)^T$

$x_{134} = A_{134}^{-1}b_{134} \approx (1.0000,2.1650,3.1650)^T$

$x_{234} = A_{234}^{-1}b_{234} \approx (1.0550,2.1650,3.1100)^T$

$\|Ax_{123}-b\|_1\approx 0.3300$

$\|Ax_{124}-b\|_1\approx 0.1650$

$\|Ax_{134}-b\|_1\approx 0.3300$

$\|Ax_{234}-b\|_1\approx 0.1650$

So picking either the rows $124$ or $234$ from your system gives you an optimum.